# Quick fix to solve XMPP iOS VoIP background execution rejection by appestore

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, xmpp

I developed an xmpp ios chat application. The application requires the functionality of receiving the chat messages even if the application in background state. In order to achieve this,  i used VoIP background execution to stay the user session alive instead of implementing apple push notification . The application is working fine. But the problem is that, the application is rejected by the appstore(Meta data rejection). Is there any quick way to solve this issue ??? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By giving background mode capabilities would not allow to make your app live if there is no functionality of VOIP in the app.

[image]

Use Pushkit ( Silent push notification ) like whatsapp, facebook etc chat app to keep your chat functionality in background or kill state.

Let me know if i could help you in push kit or anything else.

Comment: Could you please share any link that showing the implementation of Pushkit

Comment: Kindly refer https://zeropush.com/guide/guide-to-pushkit-and-voip and https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial let me know if you need any more help in VOIP or Pushkit.

Comment: Thanks for the replay.

Comment: Hi @Hasya, due to change on iOS 13, we can no longer using VOIP push for non-voip call, and standard silent push notifications are extremely unreliable and bad, do you know how big app like Messenger, Telegram, Whatsapp,...handle this change?